# How do I split an array into pairs into new arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to test my JS ability and i have no idea how to do the following.

I have an array of data `var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];`.

I want to pair the items and return a new array of arrays eg `var newArray = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];` ect

How would I got about this

Comment: Surely a `for(let i=0, e=arr.length; i<e; i+=2)` would get you most of the way there.

Comment: welcome. To explain the downvotes, next time get sure to show what you tried, paste your code and tell us exactly where u stack

Comment: This loop will work. 
`const array2 = []` `for (let i =0; i< array.length; i+=2){array2.push(array.splice(0,2));}`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [ 4, 1, 2, 8, 9, 0 ]
var newArray = []

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=2) {
   newArray.push([arr[i], arr[i+1]])
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a scalable function that you can use to do this for you but you can also configure it so that it is flexible enough to handle any number of objects that you want by passing in `n`.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function partitionListByN(list, n = 2, reverse) {
  if(reverse) {
    return [list.splice(list.length - n).reverse()].concat(list.length > 0 partitionListByN(list, n, reverse) : list) 
  }
  return [list.splice(0, n)].concat(list.length > 0 ? partitionListByN(list, n) : list)  
}

console.log(partitionListByN(numbers, 3));
```

Whats happening is you pass in a list, we are returning a list `[firstPartition, shortenedListFromRecursiveCall]` so this will go `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]` since I passed `n` in as 3. As you can see it defaults to 2 in the params list.

It also supports a reverse setting: `console.log(partionListByN(numbers, 3, true))` this would yield `[ [ 10, 9, 8 ], [ 7, 6, 5 ], [ 4, 3, 2 ], [ 1 ] ]`

Answer (score 0):

You could take a variable for the wanted chunk size and an index and iterate as long as some elements are available.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    size = 2,
    chunks = [],
    i = 0;

while (i < array.length) chunks.push(array.slice(i, i += size));

console.log(chunks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```